Invariance of mutable references over their lifetimes
The Rustonomicon's chapter on subtyping and variance contains the passage

Also, we saw that it was not ok for us to treat &mut &'a U as a subtype of &mut &'b U, therefore we can say that &mut T is invariant over T [emphasis mine].

The claim that we cannot treat &mut &'a U as a subtype of &mut &'b U originates from the following example:
fn assign<T>(input: &mut T, val: T) {
    *input = val;
}

fn main() {
    let mut hello: &'static str = "hello";
    {
        let world = String::from("world");
        assign(&mut hello, &world);
    }
    println!("{hello}"); // use after free 
}

The chapter goes on to explicitly state that &mut &'a T is covariant over 'a.
Based on the example above, wouldn't it be correct to say that &mut &'a T is invariant over 'a? After all, the example has just established that a &mut &'static str cannot be assigned to a &mut &'world str even though 'static is a subtype of 'world. The conclusion that &mut T is invariant over T (which may or may not be correct) seems like a nonsequitor.
Is it the Rustonomicon or my understanding that's incorrect?
Update: As pointed out by @kmdreko, the Rustonomicon actually claims that &'a mut T is covariant over 'a, which is distinct from &mut &'a T being covariant over 'a.

&mut &'a T is indeed invariant over 'a, since &mut T is invariant over T. Why do you think the nomicon implies otherwise?

Later in the chapter (under the section "Variance"), there's a table with examples of covariance / invariance / contravariance. It states that &'a mut T is covariant over 'a

You are mixing up your lifetimes, 'a in &'a mut T is covariant while 'a in &mut &'a T is invariant. I hope you can see they aren't the same thing.

Indeed I am. If you want to put that into an answer, I'll accept it

I am also ok with closing the question
